# Firefox Mac alignment issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, firefox

I wrote a menu where the total width of the buttons should be always the same width of the menu bar. So i take the whitespace and devide it over the buttons.

It works on: 
 Windows: FF IE6 IE7 IE8
 Mac: Safari Chrome

But it doesnt work on Firefox on the Mac can does anyone have an idea?

The example can be found:
http://www.bobkarreman.com/menu_prototype/menu/menu.html

EDIT:

The steps i take are:

- I Calculate the whitespace.
- Divide that by the number of buttons and round it.
- Add that together with the current padding to the button.
- To be sure there are no rounding issues Each time a add the padding to a button i subtract it from the totalWhitespace and on the last LI i add the totalWhitespace.

So it can be that the last LI gets 1 or 2 pixels less or more.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you're changing the li's widths dynamically their width values are floats rather than integers. It looks to me like the browsers all handle that differently. Try doing the `Math.floor` function after it's calculated.

Comment: I Round the values and because that can cause a rounding issue i subtract the value i add to each li from the whiteSpace and on the last li i add the remaining part. So i dont see how its a float when i add it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `console` output, it looks like it is not necessarily applying the calculated padding as expected. It seems to be calculating `marLeft` to `38` (and `last` to `43`) but applying `43` to every `<a>`. I could be off, I'm only guessing at the meaning of your `console` output.

It's worth noting also that it's off by a pixel for me in Safari (the last menu's `<a>` has `padding-left: 39px` whereas the others have `padding-left: 40px`, and it is one pixel from the edge of the container).

Edit: I may be misunderstanding your `console` output, Safari is saying `marLeft` is `35` but applying `40` (except for `last`).

Edit 2: I really appreciate there being information in the console to look at. This is the right way to post an example. Thanks!

Comment: In Safari they are all on One Line and its not off looks like it because of the white right border.